# ASP.NET c# adding row to dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

i have a dataset which im using to calculate some sales figures, this data set has about 15 columns i want to add a new row to the end of the dataset to calculate the total of each column. heres an example of what the dataset looks like

```
NAME | GP   | ORD_GP | EXP   | TOTAL GP
a      206     48      -239     15 
b      0       27       0        27
```

so what i want to be able to do is add another row at the end which will calulate the sum of each row so it would look something like

```
NAME | GP   | ORD_GP | EXP   | TOTAL GP
a      206     48      -239     15 
b      0       27       0       27
TOTAL  206     75       -239    42
```

so far i have

```
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add("TOTAL");
    foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
      // add upp column data and put into toal field
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I dynamically add colums and rows to an empty dataset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712509/how-can-i-dynamically-add-colums-and-rows-to-an-empty-dataset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have  a look at the [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method:

```
private void AddTotalRow(DataTable dt)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["NAME"] = "TOTAL";
    dr["GP"] = dt.Compute("Sum(GP)", null);
    dr["ORD_GP"] = dt.Compute("Sum(ORD_GP)", null);
    dr["EXP"] = dt.Compute("Sum(EXP)", null);
    dr["TOTAL_GP"] = dt.Compute("Sum(TOTAL_GP)", null);
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

You would call this function only once, for example:

```
AddTotalRow(ds.Tables[0]);
//Now the first DataTable in your DataSet has an additonal record with the total values
```

*Edited according to your new informations*

Comment: am i correct in thinking that i call the above function in my for each loop ?

Comment: @c11ada: no, this function needs to be called only once, because `dt.Compute("Sum(Total)", null)` will sum up already the total-column of all rows implicitely. Have a look at the Link i've provided.

Comment: i tried your method but all that seems to do is add an empty row and column !! please look at the update it might clarify what im trying to achieve

Comment: @c11ada: i've edited my answer according to your new informations.

Answer (score 2):

[How to: Add Rows to a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
DataRow newCustomersRow = dataSet1.Tables["Customers"].NewRow();

newCustomersRow["CustomerID"] = "ALFKI";
newCustomersRow["CompanyName"] = "Alfreds Futterkiste";

dataSet1.Tables["Customers"].Rows.Add(newCustomersRow);
```